# Checking if SQL Query Output Will Be Ordered Based on `ORDER BY` Clause

Tags: python, sqlite, common-table-expression, sql-parser

I'm working on a project where I need to parse SQL queries and determine if the final SQL output will be ordered or not. I am checking based on the presence of an `ORDER BY` clause.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```py
def contains_outermost_order_by(sql):  
    parsed_sql = parse(sql)  
  
    for statement in parsed_sql:  
        tokens = [token for token in statement.tokens if token.ttype in Keyword or token.ttype in DML]  
        if 'ORDER BY' in ' '.join(re.sub(' +', ' ', token.value.upper()) for token in tokens):  
            return True  
  
    return False
```

However, this code only checks for the presence of `ORDER BY` in the outermost level of the query, and does not account for `ORDER BY` in subqueries or CTEs. I understand that the presence of an `ORDER BY` clause in a subquery or CTE does not necessarily mean the final output will be ordered. However, there can be some cases.

Consider:

```
1.   
SELECT *  
FROM  
    (SELECT *  
     FROM Customers  
     ORDER BY CustomerName) AS CustomerList  

2.  
WITH Orders_CTE AS  
    (SELECT *  
     FROM Orders),  
     Customers_CTE AS  
    (SELECT *  
     FROM Customers  
     ORDER BY CustomerName)  
SELECT *  
FROM Customers_CTE
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also, I'm new to SQL parsing or so. Could you provide guidance on the best way to understand a library like sqlparse, given that the documentation appears tailored to experienced users?

Comment: Neither of your examples ***guarantee*** ordering. They *may* return ordered results, but they *may* return unordered results.

Comment: Would you consider something sorted with `ORDER BY RAND()` or not?

Comment: @MatBailie, I was thinking about the following SQL queries:

1. `SELECT * FROM Customer;`
2. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY CustomerName) AS CustomerList;`

In the context of an outer query, I understand that adding/removing output columns, or joining with other subqueries, can potentially alter the order. However, I'm curious if a simple `SELECT *` could also introduce issues related to ordering.

Also, if the order is not guaranteed in the two original examples provided, does my code adequately handle the `ORDER BY` clause in all scenarios where it is guaranteed?